# Fetch id from url in block file

Tags: block, magento-1.9

What is the standard of Magento for fetch id from URL in the block file?

My URL is http://test.com/quote/savequote/view/id/7/

My XML file

```
<quote_savequote_view>
    <label>View Quote</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="quote/savequote" name="quote.savequote" template="quote/view.phtml" />
    </reference>
</quote_savequote_view>
```

Controller Action

```
public function viewAction(){
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Block File

```
public function getDetails(){
    // I want to get id here and I want to use the id in collection
}
```

Please help me what is the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solution, We can use mage register for pass data between block and controller.

```
public function viewAction(){
    $id = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $results = // your model results 
    Mage::register('quotedetails', $results);    
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->renderLayout();
}
```

Block File

```
public function getDetails(){
    return Mage::registry('quotedetails');
}
```